# HTML5 datalist: Show dropdown only when arrow clicked

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html-datalist

I'm using a HTML5 datalist (**Chrome**) . I want the dropdown to open only when the arrow is clicked, not when the select field is clicked directly. How can I do that?

```css
input::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
              opacity: 100;
           }
```

```html
 <input list="browsers" name="myBrowser" />
        <datalist id="browsers">
          <option value="Chrome">
          <option value="Firefox">
          <option value="Internet Explorer">
          <option value="Opera">
          <option value="Safari">
        </datalist>
```

Comment: Is there a good reason for this? I ask because changing the way that standardised UI controls work is only going to lead to a confusing experience for your customers.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an arrow...

Comment: @JBDouble05 — Perhaps your browser doesn't support datalist, or implements it with a different UI. There is an arrow in Chrome.

Comment: Good point @Quentin it seems it's only fully supported in Chrome, Chrome mobile and Samsung Internet.

Comment: @Adam Garner: The normal case is that no item is selected from the dropdown. That's why I don't want the dropdown list to be shown when clicking the input field.

Comment: Even after removing all events of that element (in the console), the dropdown list is still shown